# Freefall time of human body with/without air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, free-fall

I am trying to calculate how long does it take for a human body ($100 \;\text{kg}$) to fall from $120 \;\text{m}$ with what end speed. (With air and in vacuum). I googled something about drag coefficient or drag force.

I am not very educated in physics so that's why I am asking.

Comment: There's no reason why terminal velocity will be reached after $120\mathrm{m}$: it could be reached before or after that distance. Certainly you can't define a *'terminal velocity at $120\mathrm{m}$'* . Also, there's no terminal velocity by freefall in vacuum.

Comment: See; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): If there's drag it it by definition not a free fall.

Answer (score 0):

The (pressure) drag on an object depends on its frontal area. If the skydiver is spread out, he will have a higher drag than if he looks like a pencil with his head towards the ground. Thus, the terminal velocity depends on body configuration.